# Is there a way to ensure a request is coming from a trusted UI application?

Tags: java, spring-boot, ember.js, user-permissions

So to give you a background, we have a backend application that has a huge number of APIs (Spring boot framework). And then there is a UI application with a mix of React and Ember.js. We are using OAuth2.0 access token.

Each page of the UI may use a number of API resources and permissions of the pages (including actions and buttons) are managed separately than permissions for accessing APIs directly.

Now the issue is that in order to stop anyone with their access token can directly call any API. To stop that, we decided to link the services/resources used in each page or a button to the route url (Ember.js routes) so that based on the user's permission to those routes, we determine whether they have access to particular service in the backend or not. In other words, if a user sends a request to a service directly and say that service is linked to a page that he doesn't have access to in the UI world, then security check stop him.

However, this is now becoming a headache. The pages are constantly changing, some services are being removed or new services are added and we have to continously maintain the SQL scripts to keep the linkage between the two. Now to mention that due to hierarchical structure of the UI (routes) this has become even more complicated.

Now I was wondering, if we could determine that a request is coming from a UI then we don't need to check the permission to API and given the UI won't be rendered if they don't have access to it, we can safely let the request comes in and served. And if the same user uses his UI token to access the API directly we simply block it. If a user need direct access to an API, then they have to get a special token used for API (Some user may need to use API directly for their).

Now the question is how can we determine the request is from UI and that UI page is the one we trust? I did a search in internet but couldn't really find anything any framework or protocol for this. Is it even possible?

Comment: You could do this using a [nonce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_nonce), or something similar. When the user requests the UI, if they are authorized, you can send them a one-time-use token / nonce. This token will be valid for X minutes, or one use. The next request to the server must include this nonce, and on the response, you will provide them a new one. If any request comes in without a nonce, or with one that is expired, you reject the request.

Comment: thanks but how does that help? If I get a nonce from the UI and then use it to directly send a request to an API service, I can do anything with it and I get a new nonce again? Or maybe I am missing something here?

Comment: No, it really isn't. Once you hand information over to be processed by a client, you can't trust it anymore--someone might be fiddling with a rooted Android device, or in the case of a browser could easily pop open the console and start editing things. Your server has to enforce all policies itself.

Answer (score 1):

> how can we determine the request is from UI and that UI page is the one we trust?

You probably can't. To do this you'd need a trusted execution environment, in other words, one in which the user is not in total control. Examples of this are credit card point of sale machines, cable/satellite TV boxes, and the ARM TrustZone. These environments allow you to store a secret on the client device that isn't visible to the user. You can then use this secret to communicate with your code in the trusted environment without the user having access to it.

Your user's web browser however, is not a trusted execution environment. The user can see all the cookies, local and session storage, etc on your web page and they can use them to make requests directly via something like curl such that the requests look the same as ones from the browser.

Not in the question, but what SHOULD you do?
It's sounds like it might be a pain given how you have things set up now, but do all your security and permissioning on the API. If you don't want users to use their tokens to call the API a ton in an automated way, then implement rate limiting on the tokens.
It may also be useful to revisit the reasons why you have this setup in the first place. Are users calling the API directly overloading servers? Is it just a UX concern around what the user sees on the page? Is it an access concern around what data and actions the user has access to?

Comment: Any idea how websites normally permit access to pages whilte protecting their API?

Comment: They don't. They protect the API. The primary question about security is which data the user can read or write. From that determinate which UI can the user see. Not the other way around.

Comment: @Lux ok so the question is how can we determine which UI part to render from the API? Lets say, in an banking app, you are not allowed to transfer money, in its ui, we need to somehow disable or hide transfer window. Do we do this by checking the permission of the transfer service from the API server? What if that page is using near 20 other API services and the user doesn't have access to 10 of them... do we need to check all the 20 services for the permission? Our application is way bigger than a banking app.

Comment: @xbmono don't think of it from the perspective of "what api services can the user access?" think of it more on a feature/product level. If a user can't transfer money in a banking app, then why not? Is it a child and their guardian has disabled transfers for them? If so, there's probably some service where the guardian configured that access, and you can can query that service to see if the transfer page should be displayed to the user.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry if I've totally missed it, but isn't this just a simple case of Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)?

You'd set the allowed CORS on each controller to be that of your UI/frontend domain.

```
@CrossOrigin(value = "example.com")
@RestController
public class PrivateController {

}
```

The controller will now reject anything that doesn't come from `example.com`.

Comment: I don't think this helps. We won't have multiple domains. It's always one domain. Also, this may stop a user from accessing the API directly. We don't want that. We basically want to manage UI permissions separated from API permissions and to stop a UI access token to access API directly, although given the answers so far, I am becoming convinved that it's not possible. Interesting to know what other websites do and how they protect their API

Comment: Okay that makes a little more sense... I build micro services with Springboot and Ember all day every day, sounds like perhaps you need to seperate your API layer to it's own service, and use something like Zuul to stop UI requests going down stream to the API service.

Comment: They are separated. We have microservices, API gateway etc. This is not a small application. That's why managing all these permissions becoming a pain

Comment: I checked Zuul. Doesn't seem to help the issue I described. Thanks anyway